# Introduction on first visit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently designing my website, and my problem is simple : actually humble beginner in Javascript, I would require some advanced knowledge for this problem.

I have a div .introduction, in which I have the introduction of my website with a CSS animation of my logo, and I would like this div to play ONLY on the first visit of my website, whatever the page (not only on the homepage).

So far so good. But here are the troubles.

I would like the div to play the animation on the first visit of the site, but ALSO I would like a refresh of the page to be **counted** as a first visit. Also, I would like the div te be on display : hidden if it's not played, or when it's played to set a timer for it to be hidden after 6.2 seconds.

[Here](https://sachatourtoulou.com/) is an explicit example with an intro that plays only on first visit of the site, whatever the page, and it also works when the page is refreshed.

This is what I have got so far :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0].style.display = 'none';
}, 6200);

const firstLoad = sessionStorage.getItem("pageHasBeenLoaded");

if (firstLoad === "no") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0].style.display = "none";
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0].style.display = "grid";
    sessionStorage.setItem("pageHasBeenLoaded", "no" );
}
```

I know it's kinda messy but again, I'm beginning with Javascript.

It works for the most part, except the refresh part, but maybe there is a cleaner and simpler way to do that... If some of you guys know how to do it properly, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all [this](https://sachatourtoulou.com/) is a catchy website. (and yeah, noticed that the introduction loads even after reloading). And as for this part of your code:

```
if (firstLoad === "no") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

When the visitor loads the introduction page, does the `firstLoad` variable get set to "no"? Because that's what this condition suggests.
(This won't affect how your code works but will help you in managing it better) When a visitor loads the page, set that variable to "yes" instead of "no". Then this will be the comparison:

```
if (firstLoad == "yes") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Also note the `==` instead of `===` which is a **strict** comparison. This might be the only issue because of the **strict**(===) comparison.

---

An addition to that, if you also want it not to load ever again for the user you can implement `localStorage` in place of `sessionStorage`

---

Another thing, I'm not sure what this section is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0].style.display = 'none';
}, 6200);
```

but seems like a `setTimeout` function, that plays the animation then stops it after 6200 seconds, if that's the case, you can also put this inside the `if` condition such that if the user does not have the `firstLoad` set to "yes", then it will play

Comment: I second using local storage.